# Real-time passing argument to the callback of checkbox widget in TkInter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
            detectionEnableCheckBoxFrame = tk.Frame(root)
            detectionEnableCheckBoxVal = tk.IntVar()
            detectionEnableCheckBoxVal.set(0)
            detectionEnableCheckBox = tk.Checkbutton(detectionEnableCheckBoxFrame, 
                                                     text='Enable Spike Detection', 
                                      variable=detectionEnableCheckBoxVal, 
                                 command=spikeDetectionEnableCallback)
            detectionEnableCheckBox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            detectionEnableCheckBoxFrame.pack(fill=tk.X)
```

I am using this piece of code to create a checkbox. I would like to know how to pass the value of the `tk.IntVar()` to the callback in real time when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
detectionEnableCheckBox = tk.Checkbutton(detectionEnableCheckBoxFrame, 
                                                 text='Enable Spike Detection', 
                                  variable=detectionEnableCheckBoxVal, 
                             command=lambda: spikeDetectionEnableCallback(arg))
```

Solved using lambda Function.